# Set default printer

Tags: printing, default

I have 2 printers. I want to select the default printer.

Using CUPS, I selected the printer using Set the Server Default.

However print jobs still print on the wrong printer.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What application are you printing from?  Some applications will print to the last printer it already printed to.

Comment: Writer in OfficeWriter.

Comment: Maybe after a reboot or a complete program exit, they are supposed to go to the default printer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the system-wide cups defaults setting there is also a user-specific one under `~/.cups/lpoptions`

From the [lpoptions(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/de/man1/lpoptions.1.html) manual page:

> ```
>    When run by the root user, lpoptions gets and sets default options and
>    instances for all users in the /etc/cups/lpoptions file.  Otherwise, the
>    per-user defaults are managed in the ~/.cups/lpoptions file.
> ```

So try running `lpoptions` as your own user or edit the file in your home directory manually.

Comment: I have no loptions file anywhere on my system.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/swriter -pt Brother_HL-2240_series Blood_Sugar_Log.odt

I made a thunar custom action so it works on any file.

/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/swriter -pt Brother_HL-2240_series %F

This method is better.

system/printers and right-click the relevant printer and choose "set as default"